# How set interval for timeUpdate JS AUDIO

Tags: javascript, audio, intervals

Can I change event frequency(Its log every 250 ms(+-) ):

```
this._track.addEventListener('timeupdate', (event) => {
        console.log(event);
    })
```

The documentation says:

> The event frequency is dependant on the system load, but will be thrown between about 4Hz and 66Hz (assuming the event handlers don't take longer than 250ms to run). User agents are encouraged to vary the frequency of the event based on the system load and the average cost of processing the event each time, so that the UI updates are not any more frequent than the user agent can comfortably handle while decoding the video.

For example I want to replace 250 ms with 1000ms. Thnx!